# VB.NET Execute a Sub on a UserControl

Tags: vb.net, interface, user-controls

I have a number of user controls that I want to populate onto a form (Inside a FlowLayoutPanel (flpContainer)).

Each user control Implements an Interface which contains the following:

```
ReadOnly Property Total1 As Dictionary(Of String, Double)

ReadOnly Property Total2 As Dictionary(Of String, Double)

ReadOnly Property Total3 As Dictionary(Of String, Double)

Sub DoCalculation()

Sub DoValidation()

Sub Clear()
```

Is there a way that, no matter which control is loaded on the form at the current time, that i can just call e.g. flpContainer.controls(0).Clear() and VB does the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting to your interface:

```
If TypeOf flpContainer.Controls(0) Is myInterface Then
  DirectCast(flpContainer.Controls(0), myInterface).Clear()
End If
```

Comment: So cast to the interface rather than the user control?

Comment: @Richard Yes.  Interfaces were designed to help you not care which control it is.